# Importing and using a class without it appearing as an object on the current class

Tags: typescript

I have a config class:

```
export class Config {
    color = 'blue'
    type = 'ball';
}
```

and I want to use that config in another class, like this:

```
export class Game {

    private config;
    color;

    constructor(config: Config) {
        this.config = config;
        this.color = this.config.color;

    }
}
```

Now, when I create an instance of `new Game(config)`, the config object appears on the `Game` class, like `Game.config.blue`.

Is there any way to hide that property, but still use the config variables?

Comment: When you say "appears on the Game class" where exactly are you seeing this? I just copied what you have into the TS playground and creating an instance of `Game` does not yield access to the config property.

Comment: If it is private you won't have access. As Brocco says it cannot happen. Anyway your code looksbad to me. I don't see the case where you should do this `this.color = this.config.color;` instead of accesing the object itself without a variable

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to hide that property, but still use the config variables

All properties on `this` will be available at runtime. However using `private` will prevent you to use it *from TypeScript*.

Answer (score 0):

Using `private` should suffice, as TypeScript won't let you access them from outside the class. But if you ***really*** need to enforce a JavaScript's style privacy, you could do this:

```
class Game {
    public color;
    public getConfig;

    constructor(config: Config) {
        var config = config;    // <--Private
        this.color = config.color;

        // If you need an accessor... 
        this.getConfig = function() {
            return config;
        };
    }
}

var baseball = new Game({color: 'blue', type: 'ball'}); 
console.log(baseball.config); // undefined
console.log(baseball.getConfig()); // {color: 'blue', type: 'ball'}
```